# Using fillna() with inplace=True using other column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to use fillna() to avoid NaN values on my dataset.

I'm interested in replacing new values depending on other column's value.

For example, I'm going to use the famous 'titanic' dataframe to better explain myself. Imagine I want to replace 'age' NaN values with the mean age of each 'embark_town'.

First of all, mean_age would be calculated as follows:

```
mean_age = round(titanic.groupby('embark_town')['age'].mean(), 2)
```

Being the result:

```
embark_town
Cherbourg      30.81
Queenstown     28.09
Southampton    29.45
Name: age, dtype: float64
```

So, to replace NaN age values with the proper mean_age value of each row using 'embark_town' column, I did this:

```
titanic['age'] = titanic['age'].fillna(titanic['embark_town'].map(mean_age))
```

And it works fine,

But my question is: how can it be done without using .map() and using inplace=True instead? Do I have to use .loc or .iloc?

Please, can anyone give me a hint or explain me better how to use fillna() with inplace=True depending on other column value.

Just curious,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `titanic['age'].fillna(titanic['embark_town'].map(mean_age), inplace=True)` works fine

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know what am I doing wrong using inplace=True. Thnks again

Comment: my error was doing titanic['age']= titanic['age'].fillna(titanic['embark_town'].map(mean_age), inplace=True) it only worked if I did titanic['age']= titanic['age'].fillna(titanic['embark_town'].map(mean_age), inplace=False)

Comment: Don't assign a value when using `inplace = True`, it modifies the original dataframe